# PyQt5 implement a simple ImageViewer (menu + image)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

i'm beginner in PyQt. I want to create window with simple menu and label with image.
I searched how to create menu and how to show image in label, but can't combine these 2 things.

Code for menu(image doesn't display):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import cv2


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('./liver.bmp')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        # Create new action
        openAction = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), '&Open', self)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.setStatusTip('Open document')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openCall)

        # Create menu bar and add action
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)


    def openCall(self):
        pixmap = QPixmap('./default.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

[screenshot(image doesn't display)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqQtF.png)

Code without menu with displayed image:

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import cv2


class ImageViewer(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setup_ui()

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.image_label = QLabel()
        self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('./default.png'))

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()  # adding widgets to layot
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.image_label)

        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)  # set layot


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    viewer = ImageViewer()
    viewer.show()
app.exec_()
```

How to combine these 2 things????

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add self to all the label variable, and it works,

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import cv2


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('./liver.bmp')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        # Create new action
        openAction = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), '&Open', self)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.setStatusTip('Open document')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openCall)

        # Create menu bar and add action
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)


    def openCall(self):
        pixmap = QPixmap('./default.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: Thank you! The promblem was in the size of label. It was so tiny and didn't saw it, i'm so stupid...